# Not getting proper voltage reading from my OBDII reading app

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, obd-ii

I'm working on a OBDII reading app to read basic data such as (in this case) voltage. I've tried other apps and it works just fine to read the voltage of the OBDII adapter, so there's nothing wrong with the adapter itself.

I'm using the [OBDII api from pires on github](https://github.com/pires/obd-java-api). When connection to my OBDII via Bluetooth successfully I get `0,0V` and after that I get a Error saying: `"Error running 01 42, response: ...UNABLETOCONNECT"` (you can see this in the log cat below)

[image]

**BTHandler.java**

```
public class BTHandler {

    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

    final ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList();
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private BluetoothDevice device;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private BluetoothSocket socket;
    private String status;
    private int pPlatform = Constants.SPA;
    private int mState;
    private boolean connectionStatus = false;

    public BTHandler(Context context, Handler handler) { // Konstruktor
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    public void write(String s) {
        mConnectedThread.sendRawCommand(s);
        Log.v("write", "write");
    }

    public void connect(String deviceAddress) {
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(deviceAddress);
        mConnectThread.start();
    }

    private void guiHandler(int what, int arg1, String obj) {
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.what = what;
        msg.obj = obj;
        msg.arg1 = arg1;
        msg.sendToTarget();
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

        public ConnectThread(String deviceAddress) {
            mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            device = mAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);

            BluetoothAdapter mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            BluetoothDevice device = mAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
            UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                //socket.connect();
                //Log.v("connect", "connect");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                //Log.v("exception", "e");
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes;

            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
                Log.v("connect", "connect");
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                Log.v("connectException", "e");
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                    Log.v("close", "close");
                } catch (IOException closeException) {
                    Log.v("closeException", "e");
                }
                guiHandler(Constants.TOAST, Constants.SHORT, "Connection Failed");
                return;
            }
            guiHandler(Constants.CONNECTION_STATUS, Constants.STATE_CONNECTED, "");

            mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
            mConnectedThread.start();
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private ObdMultiCommand multiCommand;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            connectionStatus = true;
            mmSocket = socket;

            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;


            switch (pPlatform) {
                case Constants.SPA:
                    multiCommand = new ObdMultiCommand();
                    multiCommand.add(new OdbRawCommand(SPA.VOLTAGE));
                    break;
            }

            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v("e", "e");
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            OBDcmds();
            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs


            try {
                ModuleVoltageCommand voltageCommand = new ModuleVoltageCommand();

                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    //System.out.println("Inside while");

                    // TODO handle commands result
                    Log.d("d", "Voltage: " + voltageCommand.getFormattedResult());
                    try {
                        voltageCommand.run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                        voltageCommand.getFormattedResult();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("inside catch before while");
            }
            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final







            /*
            try {
                ModuleVoltageCommand voltageCommand = new ModuleVoltageCommand();

                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                    voltageCommand.run(mmSocket.getInputStream(), mmSocket.getOutputStream());
                    voltageCommand.getFormattedResult();
                    Log.d("Log", "Voltage:" + voltageCommand.getFormattedResult());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            */


            //ModuleVoltageCommand voltageCommand = new ModuleVoltageCommand();

            /*while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    voltageCommand.run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
                    voltageCommand.getCalculatedResult();
                    Log.d("Log", "Voltage:" + voltageCommand.getResultUnit());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }*/


        }

        private void OBDcmds() { // execute commands

            try {
                new EchoOffCommand().run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                new LineFeedOffCommand().run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                new TimeoutCommand(100).run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                new SelectProtocolCommand(ObdProtocols.AUTO).run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                //ISO_15765_4_CAN

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("OBDcmds", "e");
                // handle errors
            }
        }

        // CALL this to MainActivity
        public void sendRawCommand(String s) {

            try {

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("sendRawCommand", "e");
            }
        }
        /*
        // Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        */

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button b1;
    BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    FragmentHostCallback mHost;
    BTHandler btHandler;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case BTHandler.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            setContentView(R.layout.activity_connected);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.title_connected_to, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.v("Log", "Connected");
                            break;
                        case BTHandler.STATE_NONE:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.title_not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btHandler = new BTHandler(MainActivity.this, mHandler);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        //init();

        if (mAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.device_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            if (!mAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        }
        //BTHandler btHandler = new BTHandler(MainActivity.this, mHandler);
        //btHandler.connect("");
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        //String voltage = ("ATRV");

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.connect:
                onConnect(); //Operation
                Log.v("Log", "Pressed onClick");
                break;
            case R.id.getValue:
                btHandler.write(SPA.VOLTAGE);
                Log.v("getValue","" + SPA.VOLTAGE);
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.enable_bluetooth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void onConnect() {
        ArrayList deviceStrs = new ArrayList();
        final ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList();

        BluetoothAdapter mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set pairedDevices = mAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (Object device : pairedDevices) {
                BluetoothDevice bdevice = (BluetoothDevice) device;
                deviceStrs.add(bdevice.getName() + "\n" + bdevice.getAddress());
                devices.add(bdevice.getAddress());
            }
        }

        // show list
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice,
                deviceStrs.toArray(new String[deviceStrs.size()]));

        alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(adapter, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                int position = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
                String deviceAddress = devices.get(position);

                btHandler.connect(deviceAddress);
                //btHandler.write();

            }
        });
        alertDialog.setTitle("Paired devices");
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Constants.java**

```
public interface Constants {
    int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    int TOAST = 1;
    int SHORT = 0;
    int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;
    int CONNECTION_STATUS = 1;
    int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
    String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
    int SPA = 1;
}
```

**SPA.java**

```
public interface SPA {
    String VOLTAGE = "AT RV";
}
```

Comment: any help is appreciated!